# Php email inquiry form - add BCC

Tags: php, bcc

The code below is used on my site to send e-mail/inquiry. I try add an additional e-mail address on BCC, but can't figure out how to to this. so your help would be welcome. Thanks in advance for support !

```
if($_POST)

{

    if(function_exists('pt_check_captch_cond'))

    {

        if(!pt_check_captch_cond())

        {

            $url = get_permalink($post->ID);

            if(strstr($url,'?'))

            {

              $url = $url."&emsg=captch";

            }else

            {

                $url = $url."?emsg=captch";           

            }

            wp_redirect($url);

            exit;

        }

    }

    $yourname = $_POST['inq_name'];

    $youremail = $_POST['inq_email'];

    $inq_phone = $_POST['inq_phone'];

    $frnd_comments = $_POST['inq_msg'];

    $pid = $_POST['pid'];



    $post_title = '<a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.$post->post_title.'</a>'; 

    $to_name = get_post_meta($post->ID,'email',true);

    $to_email = get_post_meta($post->ID,'email',true);



    if($to_email=='')

    {

        $to_email = get_option('admin_email');



    }

    ///////Inquiry EMAIL START//////

    global $upload_folder_path;

    $clientdestinationfile =  TEMPLATEPATH."/library/notification/send_inquiry.txt";

    //$message1 = file_get_contents($clientdestinationfile);

    $message1 =  implode(',',file($clientdestinationfile));

    $filecontent_arr1 = explode('[SUBJECT-STR]',$message1);

    $filecontent_arr2 = explode('[SUBJECT-END]',$filecontent_arr1[1]);

    $subject = $filecontent_arr2[0]. __(' for ').'"'.$post->post_title.'"';



    $client_message = $filecontent_arr2[1];

    $yourname_link = __('<br>De la : ').$yourname.__('<br>Telefon : ').$inq_phone.'<br><br>Trimis de pe www.BucovinaCazare.ro - <b><a href="'.get_option('siteurl').'">'.get_option('blogname').'</a></b>.';

    /////////////customer email//////////////

    $search_array = array('[#$to_name#]','[#$post_title#]','[#$frnd_subject#]','[#$frnd_comments#]','[#$your_name#]');

    $replace_array = array($to_name,$post_title,$frnd_subject,nl2br($frnd_comments),$yourname_link);

    $client_message = str_replace($search_array,$replace_array,$client_message);

/*  echo "From : $youremail  Name : $yourname <br>";

    echo "To : $to_email  Name : $to_name <br>";

    echo "Subject $subject <br>";

    echo "$client_message";

    exit;*/

    if($to_email)

    {

        sendEmail($youremail,$yourname,$to_email,$to_name,$subject,$client_message,$extra='');

    }

    //////Inquiry EMAIL END//////// 

    $url = get_permalink($post->ID);

    if(strstr($url,'?'))

      {

          $url = $url."&send_inquiry=success";

      }else

      {

            $url = $url."?send_inquiry=success";              

      }

    wp_redirect($url);

}
```

Comment: I think this should be added to `extra` var

Comment: sendEmail() looks like a custom function. Where is it defined?